# How do I change the home page of an app service after deploying an application into web apps

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have deployed an application into webapps in azure but was not able to see my home page of my application . Instead it shows the default page of microsoft .How do i change the home page of the application app service

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the content of your app, but you might have to **change the default documen**t:

> The default document is the web page that's displayed at the root URL
>   for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. To add a
>   new default document, click New document.

See: [Configure default documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-default-documents)

Comment: Hi martin . I dont see any default document option in azure portal . I am using free trial subscription